# Image Capture on mac won't delete photos/videos off iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, image-capture

My iPhone is running of of space so I connected it to my mac, ran Image Capture, chosen the ~40ish biggest videos on my phone (sort by size), click delete, app shows "Deleting...", then it disappears (no error) and videos are still there - both on screen and on the phone. Nothing happened.

What's the issue?
MacOS 10.14.7, 
Macbook pro 15" 2019,
iPhone XS iOS 13.3.1

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your iPhone has strict Privacy and Security measures in place. You should try deleting/modifying photos via an Apple App. If that doesn't work, then it probably won't work on any app. Your iPhone's SSD is probably mounted as Read Only.

Comment: RE: "You should try deleting/modifying photos via an Apple App." -- **Image Capture is an Apple application!** I also do not have any problem deleting any file that Image Capture lists on my iPhone.

Comment: I thought you said that it wouldn't delete. Also, sorry for the confusion, I meant Finder or Photos when I said Apple application. Make sure that you Trust your Computer in the iPhone prompt when you connect your computer to the Mac. Also, you can open Storage settings on your iPhone and see which videos are taking up a lot of space. You can also delete the videos from there.

Comment: I'm only seeing the bulk space photos and videos take - can't see individual big videos. The "trust this computer" is enabled ofcourse otherwise I wouldn't be able to see any photo or video from the iPhone on the mac